# iterate map by value to find key from an array js

Tags: javascript

So im trying to match the value from one array which contain object literal item to a map which also have the same format as the array to get the key , the data from the array contains object for example:

```
[{r: 255 , g : 245 , b : 1 , a : 255}...etc]
```

and my map also contain the same format of the value. I check out a stackoverflow answer which put the map object into an array and filter it, but when i filter it, it give me all the keys in the map entries() instead of the only one that i wanted. my Code:

```
 function forFilter(mapvalue, arrvalue) {
   if (String(mapvalue) === String(arrvalue)) {
     return true
   }
   return false
 }

 function change_data(array) {
   console.log(array)
   let finlastring = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     let mapkey = [...mapped.entries()]
       .filter(({
         1: v
       }) => forFilter(v, array[i]))
       .map(([k]) => k);
     finlastring.push(mapkey)
   }

   return finlastring;
 }
```

So the input are an array of rgba value eg :[{r: 255 , g : 245 , b : 1 , a: 255}...] and the map data are after `[...mapped.entries()]`

```
[
  [ '0', { r: 255, g: 215, b: 53, a: 255 } ],
  [ '1', { r: 255, g: 254, b: 54, a: 255 } ],
  [ '2', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 55, a: 255 } ],
  [ '3', { r: 255, g: 254, b: 56, a: 255 } ],
  [ '4', { r: 255, g: 254, b: 57, a: 255 } ],
  [ '5', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 58, a: 255 } ],
  [ '6', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 59, a: 255 } ],
  [ '7', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 60, a: 255 } ],
  [ '8', { r: 255, g: 245, b: 61, a: 255 } ],
  [ '9', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 62, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'a', { r: 255, g: 245, b: 1, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'b', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 2, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'c', { r: 255, g: 215, b: 3, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'd', { r: 255, g: 245, b: 4, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'e', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 5, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'f', { r: 255, g: 215, b: 6, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'g', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 7, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'h', { r: 255, g: 121, b: 8, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'i', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 9, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'j', { r: 255, g: 253, b: 10, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'k', { r: 255, g: 254, b: 11, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'l', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 12, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'm', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 13, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'n', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 14, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'o', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 15, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'p', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 16, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'q', { r: 255, g: 253, b: 17, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'r', { r: 255, g: 253, b: 18, a: 255 } ],
  [ 's', { r: 255, g: 215, b: 19, a: 255 } ],
  [ 't', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 20, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'u', { r: 255, g: 235, b: 21, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'v', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 22, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'w', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 23, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'x', { r: 255, g: 245, b: 24, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'y', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 25, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'z', { r: 255, g: 253, b: 26, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'A', { r: 255, g: 254, b: 27, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'B', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 28, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'C', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 29, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'D', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 30, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'E', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 31, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'F', { r: 255, g: 25, b: 32, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'G', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 33, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'H', { r: 255, g: 215, b: 34, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'I', { r: 255, g: 245, b: 35, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'J', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 36, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'K', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 37, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'L', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 38, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'M', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 39, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'N', { r: 255, g: 125, b: 40, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'O', { r: 255, g: 215, b: 41, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'P', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 42, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'Q', { r: 255, g: 215, b: 43, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'R', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 44, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'S', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 45, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'T', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 46, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'U', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 47, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'V', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 48, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'W', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 49, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'X', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 50, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'Y', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 51, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'Z', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 52, a: 255 } ],
  [ ' ', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 63, a: 255 } ],
  [ '!', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 64, a: 255 } ],
  [ '"', { r: 255, g: 245, b: 65, a: 255 } ],
  [ '#', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 66, a: 255 } ],
  [ '$', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 67, a: 255 } ],
  [ '%', { r: 255, g: 125, b: 68, a: 255 } ],
  [ '&', { r: 255, g: 245, b: 69, a: 255 } ],
  [ "'", { r: 255, g: 225, b: 70, a: 255 } ],
  [ '(', { r: 255, g: 253, b: 71, a: 255 } ],
  [ ')', { r: 255, g: 253, b: 72, a: 255 } ],
  [ '*', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 73, a: 255 } ],
  [ '+', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 74, a: 255 } ],
  [ ',', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 75, a: 255 } ],
  [ '-', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 76, a: 255 } ],
  [ '.', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 77, a: 255 } ],
  [ '/', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 78, a: 255 } ],
  [ ':', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 79, a: 255 } ],
  [ ';', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 80, a: 255 } ],
  [ '<', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 81, a: 255 } ],
  [ '=', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 82, a: 255 } ],
  [ '>', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 83, a: 255 } ],
  [ '?', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 84, a: 255 } ],
  [ '@', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 85, a: 255 } ],
  [ '[', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 86, a: 255 } ],
  [ '\\', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 87, a: 255 } ],
  [ ']', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 88, a: 255 } ],
  [ '^', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 89, a: 255 } ],
  [ '_', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 90, a: 255 } ],
  [ '`', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 91, a: 255 } ],
  [ '{', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 92, a: 255 } ],
  [ '|', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 93, a: 255 } ],
  [ '}', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 94, a: 255 } ],
  [ '~', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 95, a: 255 } ]
]
```

Supposedly, I wan filter the key from the map array which matches the input value {r:255 ,g: 245 , b :1 , a: 255} as the key are all the characters in the first index of the matrix arrays. So since the example data matches the array data with the key value of 'a' , the expected output should be 'a'

Comment: Please provide very short examples of the source data you are dealing with, boiled down to the most necessary problem relevant structure. The same for the output which would be expected from the very source data. From how the problem is currently described by words, at least I do not fully understand the requirements or the tasks needed in order to solve it. Maybe you try again on this matter too?

Comment: Little confusing. When each function is called? Can you provide the input and expected output? Where does `v` variable comes from?

Comment: the v value is the example above : {r:255 , g : 245 , b:1 , a : 255}, the for loop is for iterating the input data array, my thought process is that every single loop, the for loop would wait for the filter method to finish and if matches are found it push it into the "finalarray", then continue the loop , unless the implementation of the filter method is also utilize a for loop, then it will be a nested loop. Thus the input data will not match

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#filter` and for each value compare each key of the object with the object to compare. Instead of `array#filter`, you can also consider using `array#find` which will break as soon as it find the first match.

```
lookup.filter(arr => Object.keys(obj).every(k => obj[k] === arr[1][k]))
```

```js
const lookup = [
  [ '0', { r: 255, g: 215, b: 53, a: 255 } ],
  [ '1', { r: 255, g: 254, b: 54, a: 255 } ],
  [ '2', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 55, a: 255 } ],
  [ '3', { r: 255, g: 254, b: 56, a: 255 } ],
  [ '4', { r: 255, g: 254, b: 57, a: 255 } ],
  [ '5', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 58, a: 255 } ],
  [ '6', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 59, a: 255 } ],
  [ '7', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 60, a: 255 } ],
  [ '8', { r: 255, g: 245, b: 61, a: 255 } ],
  [ '9', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 62, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'a', { r: 255, g: 245, b: 1, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'b', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 2, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'c', { r: 255, g: 215, b: 3, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'd', { r: 255, g: 245, b: 4, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'e', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 5, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'f', { r: 255, g: 215, b: 6, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'g', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 7, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'h', { r: 255, g: 121, b: 8, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'i', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 9, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'j', { r: 255, g: 253, b: 10, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'k', { r: 255, g: 254, b: 11, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'l', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 12, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'm', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 13, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'n', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 14, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'o', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 15, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'p', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 16, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'q', { r: 255, g: 253, b: 17, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'r', { r: 255, g: 253, b: 18, a: 255 } ],
  [ 's', { r: 255, g: 215, b: 19, a: 255 } ],
  [ 't', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 20, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'u', { r: 255, g: 235, b: 21, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'v', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 22, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'w', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 23, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'x', { r: 255, g: 245, b: 24, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'y', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 25, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'z', { r: 255, g: 253, b: 26, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'A', { r: 255, g: 254, b: 27, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'B', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 28, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'C', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 29, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'D', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 30, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'E', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 31, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'F', { r: 255, g: 25, b: 32, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'G', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 33, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'H', { r: 255, g: 215, b: 34, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'I', { r: 255, g: 245, b: 35, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'J', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 36, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'K', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 37, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'L', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 38, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'M', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 39, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'N', { r: 255, g: 125, b: 40, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'O', { r: 255, g: 215, b: 41, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'P', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 42, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'Q', { r: 255, g: 215, b: 43, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'R', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 44, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'S', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 45, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'T', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 46, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'U', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 47, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'V', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 48, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'W', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 49, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'X', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 50, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'Y', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 51, a: 255 } ],
  [ 'Z', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 52, a: 255 } ],
  [ ' ', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 63, a: 255 } ],
  [ '!', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 64, a: 255 } ],
  [ '"', { r: 255, g: 245, b: 65, a: 255 } ],
  [ '#', { r: 255, g: 252, b: 66, a: 255 } ],
  [ '$', { r: 255, g: 225, b: 67, a: 255 } ],
  [ '%', { r: 255, g: 125, b: 68, a: 255 } ],
  [ '&', { r: 255, g: 245, b: 69, a: 255 } ],
  [ "'", { r: 255, g: 225, b: 70, a: 255 } ],
  [ '(', { r: 255, g: 253, b: 71, a: 255 } ],
  [ ')', { r: 255, g: 253, b: 72, a: 255 } ],
  [ '*', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 73, a: 255 } ],
  [ '+', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 74, a: 255 } ],
  [ ',', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 75, a: 255 } ],
  [ '-', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 76, a: 255 } ],
  [ '.', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 77, a: 255 } ],
  [ '/', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 78, a: 255 } ],
  [ ':', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 79, a: 255 } ],
  [ ';', { r: 255, g: 251, b: 80, a: 255 } ],
  [ '<', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 81, a: 255 } ],
  [ '=', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 82, a: 255 } ],
  [ '>', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 83, a: 255 } ],
  [ '?', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 84, a: 255 } ],
  [ '@', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 85, a: 255 } ],
  [ '[', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 86, a: 255 } ],
  [ '\\', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 87, a: 255 } ],
  [ ']', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 88, a: 255 } ],
  [ '^', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 89, a: 255 } ],
  [ '_', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 90, a: 255 } ],
  [ '`', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 91, a: 255 } ],
  [ '{', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 92, a: 255 } ],
  [ '|', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 93, a: 255 } ],
  [ '}', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 94, a: 255 } ],
  [ '~', { r: 255, g: 255, b: 95, a: 255 } ]
],
  obj = {r:255 ,g: 245 , b :1 , a: 255},
  result = lookup.filter(a => Object.keys(obj).every(k => obj[k] === a[1][k]));
console.log(result);
```